# In IE browser, Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk modulename-module failed

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I am using lazy loading concept in angular 7. I have created project with sidemenu. While routing the page in sidemenu, I am getting error as " Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk modulename-module failed". But,

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'parent', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];
```

layout-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
      path: '',
      component: LayoutComponent,
      children: [
          { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashBoardModule'}, 
          { path: 'test', loadChildren: '../test/test.module#TestModule'}, 
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
      ]
    }
];
```

layout.component.ts,

```
 navItems: NavItem[] = [
         {
          displayName: 'TEST',
          iconName: 'speaker_notes',
          route: 'test',
          children: [
            {
              displayName: 'Bulk Download',
              iconName: 'cloud_download',
              route: 'parent/test'
            }]
          }
        ]
```

Here I am getting error while "test" navigation in sidemenu.

Anyone help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: I have tried to create a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndxqbrmpjxl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to check the lazy loading and test your code, it seems that everything works well on my IE11 browser. So, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (such as using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndxqbrmpjxl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)). Besides, you could also check the [Lazy Loading Feature Modules](https://v7.angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).